# Why I get `undefined` in my custom React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I study JS and React. I can't understand why in my custom React library when I pass `React.createElement`, I get `undefined` for this: `React.createElement ("span", undefined, "Hello")`

```
function createElement(type, props, children = []) {
   if (Array.isArray(children)) {
      const setChildren = children.map(child =>
         typeof child === "object"
            ? child
            : createTextElement(child)
      );

      return {
          type,
          props: {
              ...props,
              children: setChildren
          },
      }
   }
}

const app = React.createElement("div",
                { style: { backgroundColor: "pink" } },
                [
                  React.createElement("span", undefined, "Hello"),
                  React.createElement("br")
                ]
);

React.render(app, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Try replacing `undefined` with `{}`

Comment: Why are you using this complex syntax, why not JSX

Comment: Your `if (Array.isArray(children)) {` opens a block, but doesn't close it, so maybe the rest of the code is understood badly by JS interpreter.

Comment: @Zohaib Ijaz The task says to implement in this way

Comment: @Roman Hocke I was wrong when writing. But the problem is not that

Comment: @Vs99 Best of luck

Comment: See the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=FAHgzgDghgdgfACwKYBsUHsQHpKzsIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=). You will see the `null`  is passed when no props exist.

Comment: The same goes for all [examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) on React docs. And if you look at the [source](https://github.com/alitaheri/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L131) code you will see they explicitly check for `config !== null` so if it is not `null` they will expect it to have a value and not be `undefined`.